# Losing messages when send messages using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

When sending messages from client A to a client B who still has an online presence and at the same time shut down the XMPP connection on Client B the message lost and never delivered to the Client B and I'm sure that the message came out of server-side and goes to client B but shutting down the connection in parallel with sending a message cause to losing this message ... how to solve this issue or avoid losing the message ?! 
Any suggestion, please !!

Stream management not work on this case because client B still has an online presence when the client A sent the message

Comment: For reference: also asked here: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2848

Comment: StreamManagement should work just fine even if client has online presence - each (set) of messages has to be confirmed (`ack`-ed) and if there is no confirmation from the client then the messages should be re-delivered onece the client works ok.

Comment: It's not working for me in this case, otherwise, the stream management works fine when turning off wifi and reconnect, is there any configuration in server side related to this issue to make sure that all messages received successfully, or if there is any timeout to resend the message again !!